# angular material unmet peer dependency

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to use angular material with angular 2(As angular 4 is not an option to use because of other project dependencies)
.But i think the official ,[angular material page](https://material.angular.io/) has moved to angular 4 and it doesnt support with angular 2 anymore .Because when i tried to use it with my angular 2 project using the command'

npm install --save @angular/material

i got the error

> +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.4.10
>   +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.4.10
>   `-- @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.7`
>   -- tslib@1.7.1
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\ch
>   okidar\node_modules\fsevents):
>   npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@
>   1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"}
>   )
>   npm WARN @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.7 requires a peer of @angular/core@^4.0.0
>   but none was installed.
>   npm WARN @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.7 requires a peer of @angular/common@^4.0.
>   0 but none was installed.

So my question is

1.Does angular material is still supported with angular2 ,if yes why am i getting the error

1.2.If not is there anyway i can use material design with angular2 project

Please help.Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Angular 2.0.0 beta 3, Angular 4 is mandatory 
 https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta3-cesium-cephalopod-2017-04-07

So Use angular 2.0.0 beta 2

```
npm install --save @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.2
```